# Can't manage to close Coverpop popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using CoverPop to display a popup to my customers. Everything seems so easy but somehow I'm to dumb to make the popup closeable. I have inserted a "close" link, as described in the setup. However when I click on it, nothing happens.

Only way to close the popup is by pressing the escape key on my keyboard.
I know this must be ridiculous for some of you. I'd really appreciate some help though.

Thanks.

HTML

```
<script>
    CoverPop.start({});
</script>

<div id="CoverPop-cover" class="splash">
<div class="CoverPop-content splash-center">
<h2 class="splash-title">Willkommen bei Exsys <span class="bold">Schweiz</span></h2>
<p class="splash-intro">Kunden aus Deutschland und anderen EU-Ländern wechseln bitte zu unserer <span class="bold">deutschen</span> Seite.</p>
<img src="{$ShopURL}/templates/xt_grid/img/shop-ch.png" title="EXSYS Online-Shop Schweiz" height="60" style="margin: 0 20px 0 0;" alt="Schweizer Exsys-Shop"/>
<a href="http://www.exsys.de/" alt="EXSYS Online-Shop Deutschland" title="EXSYS Online-Shop Deutschland"><img src="{$ShopURL}/templates/xt_grid/img/shop-de.png" height="60" alt="Shop Deutschland"/></a>
<p class="close-splash"><a class="CoverPop-close" href="#">Close</a></p>
</div><!--end .splash-center -->
</div><!--end .splash -->
```

CSS

```
.CoverPop-open,
.CoverPop-open body {
overflow: hidden;
}

#CoverPop-cover {
display: none;
position: fixed;
overflow-y: scroll;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
z-index: 1000;
-webkit-animation: fade-in .25s ease-in;
-moz-animation-name: fade-in .25s ease-in;
-ms-animation-name: fade-in .25s ease-in;
-o-animation-name: fade-in .25s ease-in;
animation-name: fade-in .25s ease-in;
}

.CoverPop-open #CoverPop-cover {
    display: block;
}
.splash {
    background-color:rgba(47, 99, 135, 0.9);
}

.splash-center {
    background-color: white;
    border-right: 8px solid #007ec8;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #007ec8;
    border-left: 8px solid #007ec8;
    margin: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 7px;
    width: 15%;
}   
.splash-center  p{
    margin: 20px 10px;

}
.splash-center  h2{
    font-size:16px;
    width: 100%;
    background:#007ec8;
    padding: 10px 0;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

JS

```
(function (CoverPop, undefined) {

'use strict';

// set default settings
var settings = {

        // set default cover id
        coverId: 'CoverPop-cover',

        // duration (in days) before it pops up again
        expires: 30,

        // close if someone clicks an element with this class and prevent default action
        closeClassNoDefault: 'CoverPop-close',

        // close if someone clicks an element with this class and continue default action
        closeClassDefault: 'CoverPop-close-go',

        // change the cookie name
        cookieName: '_ExsPop',

        // on popup open function callback
        onPopUpOpen: null,

        // on popup close function callback
        onPopUpClose: null,

        // hash to append to url to force display of popup
        forceHash: 'splash',

        // hash to append to url to delay popup for 1 day
        delayHash: 'go',

        // close if the user clicks escape
        closeOnEscape: true,

        // set an optional delay (in milliseconds) before showing the popup
        delay: 2000,

        // automatically close the popup after a set amount of time (in milliseconds)
        hideAfter: null
    },


    // grab the elements to be used
    $el = {
        html: document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0],
        cover: document.getElementById(settings.coverId),
        closeClassDefaultEls: document.querySelectorAll('.' + settings.closeClassDefault),
        closeClassNoDefaultEls: document.querySelectorAll('.' + settings.closeClassNoDefault)
    },


    /**
     * Helper methods
     */

    util = {

        hasClass: function(el, name) {
            return new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + name + '(\\s|$)').test(el.className);
        },

        addClass: function(el, name) {
            if (!util.hasClass(el, name)) {
                el.className += (el.className ? ' ' : '') + name;
            }
        },

        removeClass: function(el, name) {
            if (util.hasClass(el, name)) {
                el.className = el.className.replace(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + name + '(\\s|$)'), ' ').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
            }
        },

        addListener: function(target, type, handler) {
            if (target.addEventListener) {
                target.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
            } else if (target.attachEvent) {
                target.attachEvent('on' + type, handler);
            }
        },

        removeListener: function(target, type, handler) {
            if (target.removeEventListener) {
                target.removeEventListener(type, handler, false);
            } else if (target.detachEvent) {
                target.detachEvent('on' + type, handler);
            }
        },

        isFunction: function(functionToCheck) {
            var getType = {};
            return functionToCheck && getType.toString.call(functionToCheck) === '[object Function]';
        },

        setCookie: function(name, days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(+ date + (days * 86400000));
            document.cookie = name + '=true; expires=' + date.toGMTString() + '; path=/';
        },

        hasCookie: function(name) {
            if (document.cookie.indexOf(name) !== -1) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        },

        // check if there is a hash in the url
        hashExists: function(hash) {
            if (window.location.hash.indexOf(hash) !== -1) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        },

        preventDefault: function(event) {
            if (event.preventDefault) {
                event.preventDefault();
            } else {
                event.returnValue = false;
            }
        },

        mergeObj: function(obj1, obj2) {
            for (var attr in obj2) {
                obj1[attr] = obj2[attr];
            }
        }
    },


    /**
     * Private Methods
     */

    // close popup when user hits escape button
    onDocUp = function(e) {
        if (settings.closeOnEscape) {
            if (e.keyCode === 27) {
                CoverPop.close();
            }
        }
    },

    openCallback = function() {

        // if not the default setting
        if (settings.onPopUpOpen !== null) {

            // make sure the callback is a function
            if (util.isFunction(settings.onPopUpOpen)) {
                settings.onPopUpOpen.call();
            } else {
                throw new TypeError('CoverPop open callback must be a function.');
            }
        }
    },

    closeCallback = function() {

        // if not the default setting
        if (settings.onPopUpClose !== null) {

            // make sure the callback is a function
            if (util.isFunction(settings.onPopUpClose)) {
                settings.onPopUpClose.call();
            } else {
                throw new TypeError('CoverPop close callback must be a function.');
            }
        }
    };



/**
 * Public methods
 */

CoverPop.open = function() {

    var i, len;

    if (util.hashExists(settings.delayHash)) {
        util.setCookie(settings.cookieName, 1); // expire after 1 day
        return;
    }

    util.addClass($el.html, 'CoverPop-open');

    // bind close events and prevent default event
    if ($el.closeClassNoDefaultEls.length > 0) {
        for (i=0, len = $el.closeClassNoDefaultEls.length; i < len; i++) {
            util.addListener($el.closeClassNoDefaultEls[i], 'click', function(e) {
                if (e.target === this) {
                    util.preventDefault(e);
                    CoverPop.close();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // bind close events and continue with default event
    if ($el.closeClassDefaultEls.length > 0) {
        for (i=0, len = $el.closeClassDefaultEls.length; i < len; i++) {
            util.addListener($el.closeClassDefaultEls[i], 'click', function(e) {
                if (e.target === this) {
                    CoverPop.close();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // bind escape detection to document
    util.addListener(document, 'keyup', onDocUp);
    openCallback();
};

CoverPop.close = function(e) {
    util.removeClass($el.html, 'CoverPop-open');
    util.setCookie(settings.cookieName, settings.expires);

    // unbind escape detection to document
    util.removeListener(document, 'keyup', onDocUp);
    closeCallback();
};

CoverPop.init = function(options) {
    if (navigator.cookieEnabled) {
        util.mergeObj(settings, options);

        // check if there is a cookie or hash before proceeding
        if (!util.hasCookie(settings.cookieName) || util.hashExists(settings.forceHash)) {
            if (settings.delay === 0) {
                CoverPop.open();
            } else {
                // delay showing the popup
                setTimeout(CoverPop.open, settings.delay);
            }
            if (settings.hideAfter) {
                // hide popup after the set amount of time
                setTimeout(CoverPop.close, settings.hideAfter + settings.delay);
            }
        }
    }
};

// alias
CoverPop.start = function(options) {
    CoverPop.init(options);
};


}(window.CoverPop = window.CoverPop || {}));
```

**Additional information**
I quickly checked my site and these are the sections I found where the click event is present. Honestly I have no idea how they do interfere with the popup.

```
// tabs
$('ul.tabs').each(function(){

    var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

    $active = $links.first().addClass('active');
    $content = $($active.attr('rel'));

    $links.not(':first').each(function () {
        $($(this).attr('rel')).hide();
    });

    $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){

        $active.removeClass('active');
        $content.hide();

        $active = $(this);
        $content = $($(this).attr('rel'));

        $active.addClass('active');
        $content.show();

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

// track box clicks and route them to parent radio button
$('div.box-hover').click( function(e)
{
    $(this).find("input[type=radio]").click();
});
$('input[type=radio]').click(function(e){

    if (this.checked != true && $(this).hasClass('autosubmit')){
        this.checked = true;
        this.form.submit();
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});

// track box clicks to show/hide some desc (shipping/payment)
$('div.box-hover').click( function(e)
{
    // ok. wir wollen clicks auf shipping abfangen
    // und - laut tmpl - kann nur EIN passendes kind da sein
    // also geht das mit dem length check!
    if( $(this).children('p.shipping-name').length > 0)
    {
        $('div.box-hover').children('p.shipping-desc').css('display','none');
        $(this).children('p.shipping-desc').css('display','block');
    }
    if( $(this).children('p.payment-name').length > 0)
    {
        $('div.box-hover').children('p.payment-desc').css('display','none');
        $(this).children('p.payment-desc').css('display','block');
    }
});

// autosize the comment textarea
$('#comments').autosize();

// slide in/out guest account form
$("#guest").click( function(e){
    $("#cust_info_customers_password").val('');
    $("#cust_info_customers_password_confirm").val('');
    $('#guest-account').slideUp(250);
});
$("#account").click( function(e){
    $('#guest-account').slideDown(250);
});
});
```

Comment: i think you already did it right, http://jsfiddle.net/b9qpnsy5/1/ this are the codes exactly copy from the top (except i changed the CoverPop cookies so it prompts everytime). So possible other place is wrong? do you globally register the click event handler for `<a>` action element somewhere in ur codes?

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into it. I added the sections to my original posts, where I use the click event.

Comment: It works perfectly right for me too!

Comment: Not sure if I'm allowed to post links. But this would be where it does not work: www.exsys.ch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@santadani, found there is a rule to follow due to the implmentation of CoverPop itself. from your production environment, could you move the `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.exsys.ch/templates/xt_grid/javascript/CoverPop.js"></script>` to the end of document, before the `</body>` tag and try again?

It is because i saw in the CoverPop source, it grabs the element upon the script is loaded

```
    $el = {
        html: document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0],
        cover: document.getElementById(settings.coverId),
        closeClassDefaultEls: document.querySelectorAll('.' + settings.closeClassDefault),
        closeClassNoDefaultEls: document.querySelectorAll('.' + settings.closeClassNoDefault)
    },
```

which then the `document.querySelectorAll('.' + settings.closeClassDefault)` will retrieve nothing (becasue the script was loaded before the DOM are ready, therefore i suggest to try to move the script tag down)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I moved the script tag to the end of document. However, now the popup doesn't appear at all.

Comment: Don't forget to move the '<script>CoverPop.start({debug:true});</script>` to after the script tag too :)